# Did i forget something in the code java

Tags: java, android

I made 2 classes
`Score` and `ScoreDataSource`
And I found an error (red highlight) in `ScoreDataSource#cursorToScore(Cursor cursor)`.

This my complete code

First, `Score.java` :

```
public class Score {
private int correct_listening;
private int correct_reading;
private int correct_structure;
private int final_score;
private long id;
private int number;
private String userName;
private long user_id;

public Score(int number, long user_id, int correct_listening, int correct_structure, int correct_reading, int final_score) {
    this.number = number;
    this.user_id = user_id;
    this.correct_listening = correct_listening;
    this.correct_structure = correct_structure;
    this.correct_reading = correct_reading;
    this.final_score = final_score;
}

public long getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public long getUser_id() {
    return this.user_id;
}

public int getNumber() {
    return this.number;
}

public void setNumber(int number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public void setUser_id(long user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
}

public int getCorrect_listening() {
    return this.correct_listening;
}

public void setCorrect_listening(int correct_listening) {
    this.correct_listening = correct_listening;
}

public int getCorrect_structure() {
    return this.correct_structure;
}

public void setCorrect_structure(int correct_structure) {
    this.correct_structure = correct_structure;
}

public int getCorrect_reading() {
    return this.correct_reading;
}

public void setCorrect_reading(int correct_reading) {
    this.correct_reading = correct_reading;
}

public int getFinal_score() {
    return this.final_score;
}

public void setFinal_score(int final_score) {
    this.final_score = final_score;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return this.userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String toString() {
    return this.number + ". " + this.userName + "  |  " + this.correct_listening + "  |  " + this.correct_structure + "  |  " + this.correct_reading + "  |  " + this.final_score;
}

public float calculateScore(int listeningScore, int structureScore, int readingScore) {
    return (float) Math.round((float) ((((listeningScore + structureScore) + readingScore) / 3) * 10));
}
```

}

Second, `ScoreDataSource.java`.
I get an error at `Score score = new Score();`

```
public class ScoreDataSource {
private String[] allColumns;
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;

public ScoreDataSource(Context context) {
    this.allColumns = new String[]{MySQLiteHelper.USER_ID, MySQLiteHelper.SCORE_USER_ID, MySQLiteHelper.SCORE_LISTENING_CORRECT, MySQLiteHelper.SCORE_STRUCTURE_CORRECT, MySQLiteHelper.SCORE_READING_CORRECT, MySQLiteHelper.SCORE_FINAL};
    this.dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
}

public void open() throws SQLiteException {
    this.database = this.dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close() {
    this.database.close();
}

public List<Score> findAll() {
    List<Score> score = new ArrayList();
    Cursor cursor = this.database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_SCORE, this.allColumns, null, null, null, null, "final_score DESC");
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        score.add(cursorToScore(cursor));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return score;
}

public long count() {
    return DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(this.database, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_SCORE);
}

public List<Score> findAll(long id) {
    List<Score> score = new ArrayList();
    Cursor cursor = this.database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_SCORE, this.allColumns, "_id = " + id, null, null, null, "final_score DESC");
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        score.add(cursorToScore(cursor));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return score;
}

public Score findFirst(long id) {
    Cursor cursor = this.database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_SCORE, this.allColumns, "_id = " + id, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Score scores = cursorToScore(cursor);
    cursor.close();
    return scores;
}

public Score cursorToScore(Cursor cursor) {
    Score score = new Score();//<-- error here
    score.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
    score.setUser_id(cursor.getLong(1));
    score.setCorrect_listening(cursor.getInt(2));
    score.setCorrect_structure(cursor.getInt(3));
    score.setCorrect_reading(cursor.getInt(4));
    score.setFinal_score(cursor.getInt(5));
    return score;
}

public long create(Score score) {
    return this.database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_SCORE, null, putValuesToObject(score));
}

public int update(Score score) {
    return this.database.update(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_SCORE, putValuesToObject(score), "_id = " + score.getId(), null);
}

public ContentValues putValuesToObject(Score score) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.SCORE_USER_ID, Long.valueOf(score.getUser_id()));
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.SCORE_LISTENING_CORRECT, Integer.valueOf(score.getCorrect_listening()));
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.SCORE_STRUCTURE_CORRECT, Integer.valueOf(score.getCorrect_structure()));
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.SCORE_READING_CORRECT, Integer.valueOf(score.getCorrect_reading()));
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.SCORE_FINAL, Integer.valueOf(score.getFinal_score()));
    return values;
}

public int delete(long id) {
    return this.database.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_SCORE, "_id = " + id, null);
}

public int deleteAll() {
    return this.database.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_SCORE, "final_score > 0", null);
}

public void setDefaultData() {
}
}
```

Comment: you can't call default constructor as you explicitly define it with params

Answer (score 1):

```
Score score = new Score();
```

Well, since you are calling the parameter-less constructor of the `Score` class, you should create such constructor in your `Score` class:

```
public Score() {
    ...
}
```

It's not generated by the compiler, since you defined another constructor (`public Score(int number, long user_id, int correct_listening, int correct_structure, int correct_reading, int final_score) {...}`).

Answer (score 1):

> You have to put this method too in `Score.java`

```
public Score() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this fuction

```
public Score cursorToScore(Cursor cursor) {
    Score score = new Score();//<-- error here
    score.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
    score.setUser_id(cursor.getLong(1));
    score.setCorrect_listening(cursor.getInt(2));
    score.setCorrect_structure(cursor.getInt(3));
    score.setCorrect_reading(cursor.getInt(4));
    score.setFinal_score(cursor.getInt(5));
    return score;
}
```

with this function

```
public Score cursorToScore(Cursor cursor)
 {

Score score = new Score(cursor.getLong(0),cursor.getLong(1),cursor.getInt(2),cursor.getInt(3),cursor.getInt(4),cursor.getInt(5));//<-- error here

return score;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A constructor defines how an object for the class should be composed.

If a class is defined with no constructor, then a default no-argument constructor is implicitly generated and it will assign default values (null for string, 0 for primitive int and long etc) for  all your attributes

Once a constructor is explicitly defined for a class then the default no-argument constructor ceases to exist. You will have to explicitly define a no-argument constructor, if you want to replicate the default no-argument constructor mechanism

```
public Score() {    
}
```